# How to delete the property of a function from within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, this, anonymous-function

I have the following function which cannot be run concurrently:

```
function foo()
{
 if(this.running) return;
 this.running = true;
 setTimeout(function() {
  // Do Something
  delete this.running;
 }, 5000);
}
```

The above seems to work, but when I check the value of `this` within the anonymous function, it is pointing to `Window`. I am not sure if this is proper or correct method to delete the property. Can anyone advise why this is working?

Comment: `var that = this;` PS: why not switching it to `false` instead of deleting?

Comment: @zerkms, is there any difference between deleting and setting to false?

Comment: the latter looks more consistent. Absence of a property means some unknown state, whereas the state is pretty known - it's not running

Comment: @zerkms, ok, I got your point. Thanks :)

Comment: I would be amazed if more than 5% of *experienced* developers would prefer deletion.

Comment: @zerkms, in this case, I don't need the third state, that is why I am grouping the unknown state with the false state and using delete. But rest assured I would use true/false to take care of the unknown state when I do need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct because the object that invokes the anonymous function you provided in the setTimepout is the window object, to save  a closure variable with the value of this just do the following:

```
function foo()
{
 if(this.running) return;
 this.running = true;
 var self=this;
 setTimeout(function() {
  // Do Something
  delete self.running;
 }, 5000);
}
```

**Update:**

When you run foo function that was executed from X object (has X as this), it invokes the content of the function sequentially until it runs  setTimeout function, this function adds the anonymous function under the sleep queue the execution will continue executing the foo function with X object,

when each element in the sleep queue passes his timeout time, it will be invoked under the window object for all of them.

Comment: Can you explain why the above code is working despite it not being proper?

Comment: Sir, will you please check my updated answer and tell me if there is anything missing?
@QuestionOverflow

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Can you elaborate the part on how `this` in `this.running` within the anonymous function is able to point to the foo function?

Comment: The above code doesn't really work because deleting `self.running` has no effect on `this.running`.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow try to put this funtion in you console, then run `x = new foo()` you will find that x has runnng = true for the first 5 sec and then it gets undefined

Comment: Thanks, when isolated, this works. I think my case is complicated by another function running in parallel that somehow sets the running property on the window object and somehow, this managed to be read by the foo function. Kind of weird. Still trying to figure out the exact problem. But anyway, thanks for your help.